# If I Query a SQL Server VarBinary(MAX) Column, Will the Entire File be Loaded In Memory?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, varbinary

My application is using SQL Server 2008 and we need to add functionality for users to optionally be able to save any file of any size to a database table. I have set up the table similar to this format:

- FileStorageID - `int (indentity PK)` (This is also a foreign key to a different table)
- FileData - `varbinary(max)`
- FileName - `varchar(1000)`

The `FileStorage` table has a zero-to-one relationship to another table `Documentation`. The idea is that users can write either write some text, upload a file, or both.

This table looks as follows:

- DocumentationID - `int (identity PK`, FK to an "IrrelevantInterestingObject" table)
- Text - `varchar(max)`
- FileStorageID - `int (FK` to aforementioned FileStorage table)

My question is this: When I query the `Documentation` table using Entity Framework 5, and a file is present in the database, will the entire file be stored in memory? If yes, what would a reasonable threshold be before there is a noticeable performance issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you query `Documentation` table no data from related `FileStorage` table will be loaded until you load the relation either through eager, explicit or lazy loading. Once you use any such method or query `FileStorage` directly whole `FileData` for every retrieved record will be loaded to memory.